# ArgumentNullException when deserializing my object

Tags: c#

[image]I can serialize my object in soap formatting, I wrote the directory in the string variable fullPath but when I try to deserialize it, it shows me `ArgumentNullException`, why?

```
//The code in form1.
Train tr = new Train();
fullPath = "D:\\file.xml";
tr.WriteToFile(fullPath);

//WriteToFile() method in Train class.
public void WriteToFile(string path)
{
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        SoapFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
     }
}

//The code in Form2
Form1 f = new Form1();
string fullPath = f.fullPath;
try
{
     using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(f.fullPath))
     {
          SoapFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();
          tr = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as Train;
     }
 }
 catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
 {
      MessageBox.Show("ArgumentNullException: " + ex.Message);
 }
```

Comment: Can you use a debugger to find out which reference is actually `null`? Please show the contents of the serialized file.

Comment: Which line throws ArgumentNullException? Did you try debugging and see if the 'f' is null instead?

Comment: See anything in the Inner Exception that can give a lead ?

Comment: I see you form1 has property fullpath, does it actually point to the specified file?

Comment: @Codor the file contains a string array of ten elements called Exercise[].

Comment: If fullPath isn't assigned a proper value in Form1's constructor, then you probably have your problem.

Comment: I removed the try and catch blocks to let you see which line throws an exception.

Comment: It looks like the `fullPath` field/property on `f` is not getting initialized properly. Are you sure you're assigning it a value in the `Form1` constructor?